# How to calculate the difference between date of birth and the system date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the difference between a date of birth and the system date in JavaScript.

in JSP and JavaScript:

'Date Of Birth

'

```
function currentAge(DateOfBirth){
    //alert(DateOfBirth);
    var date1 = DateOfBirth;
    date1 = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").value;
    alert(date1);
    var date2 = new Date();
    alert(date2);

    // _Diff=Math.ceil((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/(one_day));

    /* var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    //var diffDays = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();  */
    //alert(_Diff);
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804367/953684

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will get much better quality help if you take the time and effort to properly format your code such that it is clean and easy for others to understand. I've taken the liberty of cleaning it up a bit here, but keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: You want the difference in days? But why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: If you need to show different periods (e.g. months, years) between two dates it could be easier to use http://momentjs.com/ library to do that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dateDiff(dateform) {
date1 = new Date();
date2 = new Date();
diff  = new Date();

date1temp = new Date(dateform.firstdate.value);
date1.setTime(date1temp.getTime());

date2temp = new Date(dateform.seconddate.value);
date2.setTime(date2temp.getTime());
diff.setTime(Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()));

timediff = diff.getTime();
days = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
dateform.difference.value = days;
return false; 
}
```

Comment: new Date(dateform.firstdate.value); - I don't think  it will work if my computer locale is different from date value in field.

Comment: Thanks  Maksym,  i used like: 'function currentAge(DateOfBirth){
          //alert(DateOfBirth);
            // = DateOfBirth;
             var date1 = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").value;
              alert(date1);
              
              var date11=new Date(date1);
              
              alert(date11);
              
            var date2 = new Date();
            alert(date2);
            alert(3);
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getYear() - date11.getYear());
            
            alert(timeDiff);
           
           
          
            
         }'

Answer (score 0):

Now its fine

```
    function currentAge(DateOfBirth){
        var date1 = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").value;
           alert(date1);

           var date11=new Date(date1);

           alert(date11);

           var date2 = new Date();
           alert(date2);
           alert(3);
           var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getYear() - date11.getYear());

           alert(timeDiff);




     }
```