# How do I get the difference days between two Dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="date" id="startDate" />
<input type="date" id="endDate" />

<script>
   $("#endDate").click(function () {
        var date1 = $("#startDate").val();
        var date2 = $("#endDate").val();
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
        alert(diffDays)​;
    });
</script>
```

getTime not work , and this message shown 
intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression
How do I get the difference days between two Dates in this case and how can getTime work with me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: You need to make `Date` objects; right now `date1` & `date2` are just strings. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804042/calculate-time-difference-with-javascript/10804367#10804367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/xtY47/

```
 $("#endDate").click(function () {
   var date1 = new Date($("#startDate").val()); //the value is yyyy-MM-dd
   var date2 = new Date($("#endDate").val());
   console.log(date2); 
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    alert(diffDays);
});
```