# Calculating difference in times in 24 hour time format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i go about calculating the duration between two times in HHMM format by Javascript.

- The input format will always be HHMM
- The input time will always be for the same day.

Thank you for your inputs.

------------------- lame attemp --------------------

```
<html>
<div>
STA:<input type="text" id="STA" onClick="timed();"> ATA: <input type="text" 

id="ATA"onClick="timed();">

DIFF: <input type="text" id="DIFF" onClick="timed();">
</div>
<div></div>

</html>
<script>
function timed(){
var x=0;
var y=0;
var o=0;
var l=0;
var a=0;
var b=0;
o=document.getElementById("STA").value;
l=document.getElementById("ATA").value;
a=o/100;
b=l/100;
x=a.split('.');
y=b.split('.');
document.getElementById("DIFF").value=x[0]-y[0]+":"+x[1]-y[1];
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You should try it, there are many different ways to do it. If you encounter any problems, then you can ask a question specifying what is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Time Difference with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804042/calculate-time-difference-with-javascript)

Comment: Tip: calculate to timestamp with Date.parse and subtract the values. This leaves you with the difference in milliseconds

Comment: However if it's the same day you can convert the time values to seconds and subtract them.

Comment: the input will be HHMM not HH:MM. How would i differentiate between hours and minutes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this script:

It works using the input you say is provided the HHMM format.

```
function timed(){
    var time1 = document.getElementById("STA").value;
    var time2 = document.getElementById("ATA").value;
    if ( time1.match(/^[0-9]{4}$/g) && time2.match(/^[0-9]{4}$/g) )
    {
        //lets calculate the difference. But values consist of four digits.
        var time1Seconds = toSeconds(time1.substr(0,2), time1.substr(2));
        var time2Seconds = toSeconds(time2.substr(0,2), time2.substr(2));

        if (!time1Seconds || !time2Seconds)
        {
            //input is not correct.
            return false;
        }

        var difference = time1Seconds - time2Seconds;
        if (difference < 0)
        {
            difference = Math.abs(difference);
        }
        var hours = parseInt(difference/3600) 
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        var minutes =  parseInt((difference/3600) % 1 *60)
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

        document.getElementById("DIFF").value =  hours + ":" + minutes;
    }
}

function toSeconds(hours, minutes)
{
    var seconds = 0;
    if ( (hours >= 0 && hours < 24) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes < 60))
    {
        seconds += (parseInt(hours)*3600) + (parseInt(minutes)*60);
        return seconds
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

How it works.
It retrieves the values from the inputs. Then it checks if both inputs have numeric input that is exactly 4 digits long. If not this function doesn't return anything.

Second divide the string into two sections. Hours and minutes for both inputs. Convert them to seconds by using `toSeconds`. This functions checks if the hours and minutes are valid, if not this function returns false. When both converted times are not false the function continues. It subtracts the values from each other. If the value is lower than zero convert it to a positive. Then convert the seconds back to hours and minutes and display in the difference input. Enjoy.

Comment: @Mitch You're welcome. I hope you learn a lot from this code and see all kind of (new) stuff that you can apply to future code on your own :-)