# how to calculate 2 date difference for indian format

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, date

i have 2 `calender` i want to `calculate` the `difference` in `no.of days`

**my question:** `date` must be in this `format dd/mm/yyyy` (date-month-year)

here is my code snippet

```js
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();

$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();

$("#datepicker2").change(function(){
 var date1 = $( "#datepicker1" ).val();
  console.log(date1);
  console.log("date 2: "+ $(this).val());
  
  var date2 = $(this).val();
  
  
  //difference calculation
  
     days = (date2- date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  
    console.log("difference: "+ days);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css">



<div class="demo">

<p>Check in Date: <input id="datepicker1" type="text"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo">

<p>Check Out Date: <input id="datepicker2" type="text"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: This question is already available on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Time Difference with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804042/calculate-time-difference-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy to do with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Something like:

```
var a = moment('1/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var b = moment('1/1/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var days = b.diff(a, 'days');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wL2f7q0w/

Answer (score 0):

For the number of days this code help with your problem

```
var date1 = $( "#datepicker1" ).val();
var date2 = $(this).val();

date1 = new Date(date1);
date2 = new Date(date2);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

alert(diffDays);
```