# how to calculate total hours in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, frontend

I need to calculate the total hours in a time span using JS,
an example of the time span

```
10:00 - 16:00
```

So the answer is: 6 hours, but how do I work that out in JS?

Comment: In what form do you have your inputs? Is it a pair of `String`s? a pair of `Date` objects? Something else?

Comment: how are you receiving the data? like a string: "10:00 - 16:00", in two strings: "10:00", "16:00", or how?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804042/calculate-time-difference-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Time Difference with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804042/calculate-time-difference-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
let dif = new Date("01/01/2018 " + "16:00").getHours() - 
new Date("01/01/2018 " + "10:00").getHours();

console.log(dif);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Using MomentJs
var a = moment([10,00] , "HH:mm");
var b = moment([16,00] , "HH:mm");
console.log(b.diff(a, 'hours'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Using Js
var a = new Date("12 May, 2018 10:00");
var b = new Date("12 May, 2018 16:00");
var hours = Math.abs(b - a) / 36e5;
console.log(hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//new Date("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")

var date1 = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00Z");
var date2 = new Date("2015-03-24T19:00:00Z");
var hours = Math.abs(date1.getHours() - date2.getHours());
console.log(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = new Date();
var finish = new Date();
start = start.setHours(10);
finish = finish.setHours(16);
var totalHours = finish - start;
totalHours = totalHours/3600000; // milleseconds in one hour
console.log(totalHours);
```